# How to replace only one character in a regular expression using with str_replace

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am trying to standardize some odd string data using regular expressions and `str_replace_all`. In some cases I want to use character sets (e.g. `[abc]`) or "wildcards" (e.g. `\d`) to locate a character to replace but I don't want to replace those character sets or wildcards.

Below, `data` is the type of data I have and `clean` is what I am trying to get:

```
data <- c("1ac 2b", "1 a", "1a b", "1a2b", "0")
clean <- c("1ac 2b", "1a", "1ab", "1a 2b", "0")
```

I have been attempting to build commands such as the following:

```
attempt1 <- str_replace_all(data, "[abc]\\d", "[abc] \\d")
attempt2 <- str_replace_all(data, " [abc]", "[abc])
```

In both of those attempts I end up losing data I want.

It seems that the second argument of `str_replace_all` accepts regular expressions but the third argument evaluates literally, so I end up replacing characters I don't want to replace.

Is there any way to transfer the value of the wildcard and character sets from the regular expression part of the command to the replace component?
Alternatively, is there an entirely different method solving this problem someone would recommend?

Aside: I'm new to regular expressions, and if anyone gives me a better term than "wildcards" I will edit my post accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should capture the characters you want to keep with `()` and then use `\\1` and `\\2` for each group.

Your `replace` and regular expressions should be:

```
data <- c("1ac 2b", "1 a", "1a b", "1a2b", "0")

attempt1 <- str_replace_all(data, "([abc])(\\d)", "\\1 \\2")
attempt2 <- str_replace_all(attempt1, " ([abc])", "\\1")

> attempt2
[1] "1ac 2b" "1a"     "1ab"    "1a 2b"  "0"
```

The second replace takes `attempt1` as input in order to apply both replacement rules. You could write both expressions in one line if you want.

```
str_replace_all(str_replace_all(data, "([abc])(\\d)", "\\1 \\2"), " ([abc])", "\\1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in base R use `gsub`. *Strategy:* Remove all whitespaces then add whitespace before digits which are no word boundaries. This should be more general.

```
gsub("(\\B\\d)", " \\1", gsub("\\s", "", x))
# [1] "1ac 2b" "1a"     "1ab"    "1a 2b"  "0"
```

Or wrapped into a function.

```
mySub <- function (x) {
  x <- gsub("\\s", "", x)
  gsub("(\\B\\d)", " \\1", x)
}
mySub(x)
# [1] "1ac 2b" "1a"     "1ab"    "1a 2b"  "0"
```

***Data***

```
x <- c("1ac 2b", "1 a", "1a b", "1a2b", "0")
```

Comment: Would you recommend using gsub instead of stringr functions?

Comment: Well, you know, it depends on what you're up to with R. If you only use it now and then, perhaps the effort is not worth learning it properly. Then it is probably enough to use a new package for each task. R is, however, an extensive programming language with a continuous logic. Quite often the logic of additional packages deviates considerably from the R logic, which can be quite confusing. That's why I do without additional packages as much as possible.

Comment: It is something like an overloaded kitchen in which there is a little machine for every task. However, with a sharp set of knives, you can do most of the tasks once you've learned how to handle these.